# Mule context having Spring application context as parent

Tags: java, spring, mule

How can a Web application load Mule context and have the Spring context as a parent?

I have tried the following(web.xml) and did not work:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.mule.config</param-name>
    <param-value>mule-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.mule.config.builders.MuleXmlBuilderContextListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>
             org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>

</listener>
```

If I switch the order of the listeners and then the following exceptions occur:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.mule.api.serialization.ObjectSerializer] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1297)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1045)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:940)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:606)
... 46 more
```

On the web.xml as shown above the application loads, however it seems that there are two separate Spring contexts pointing to different beans.

To get it working with mule with two context, need to add the following to mule-config.xml

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml" />
</spring:beans>
```

Please advise on how to solve this? A small example would be great that demonstrates on how the web app should load the Spring/Mule context and ultimately having a single Spring Context as parent in Mule.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you plz share how you resolved this issue? I am having the same issue, and the only work around i have so far is to create a new context, and do a bean lookup.

Comment: This issue was resolved by using Mule 3.7.3+. This issue had occurred on Mule 3.7.2.  There is a Jira on Mule documenting this.